# What's the limit for the amount of IDs that I can delimit?

Tags: youtube-api

I'm looking at the YouTube API doc to get video statistics, and I can't seem to find how many videos can I pull at once. For example, can I do 1,000 or 10,000 video IDs and get all of it back? Would the params allow that?

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#try-it

Also, is there a way to get historical view count for a given video over a course of time?

Answer (score 1):

1. Though not specified, it seems the max number of comma-separated list of ids is 50.
2. The API does not provide a historical view count. You would have to make one yourself on the client end by saving the views on a periodic basis.

Comment: I believe the limit actually comes from the fact, that maximum number of results (maxResults parameter) is 50.